# Performance/style: Changing an object by reference vs returning a copy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection, styles

First let me provide context:

*In C# an object passed into a method is passed via reference. The reference is only lost if the passed in object is re-instantiated with the keyword `new`*

*So, I like to do things like `var obj = Alter(obj)`**(method 1)** i.e. I pass in an object and return the object. As opposed to doing the equivalent: `Alter(obj)` **(method 2)** where the referenced object is changed the same, except by reference instead of returning a copy. I would argue the first one is better since if some daredevil coder later modifies the code to use a keyword "new"... existing code won't burn and die.*

**My question is will *method 1* use significantly more memory than *method 2* or will it cause any other performance degradation? i.e. will this invoke the GC more often?**

> > The answer is NO

Comment: I wonder if you wanted to ask this question based on a specific implementation of `Alter(obj)`?

Comment: No, this is a general question. I style my code after method 1 since I think it is more defensive. I just wanted to re-affirm that I am not doing something destructive, since for the most part it is unnecessary (but better style in my opinion).

Comment: In what way do you think method 1 is more 'defensive'?

Comment: If you are preparing for an interview you should concentrate on things such a SDLC, testing, HR style questions. Something like this isn't going to even be raised.

Comment: Let's say hypothetically, some method has various switch statements. Initially the code is written in a way that just alters the referenced object. However someone now adds a method call within the switch that returns a "new" object. You will now receive null references.

Comment: Could you post a quick code example that shows what problem you are protecting against here? If I understand you right, you are misunderstanding what would happen to an object reference that was re-set to a new object within the method. In fact... you seem to have it *backwards* if I understand you right... so, I must *not* be understanding you right.

Comment: To throw additional confusion into the mix, if you are doing what I think you want to be doing, why are you not defining the method as `void Alter(ref object)`? This way the intent of modifying the reference is clear.

Comment: @LLL your `var obj = Alter(obj);` *would* give you `nulls` if you set `obj` to `null` internally. `Alter(obj)` would *not*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Actually to be more explicit, it would give you `null` if you *returned* `null` from `Alter(obj)`. (I'm being nitpicky, but we do not yet know `Alter(obj)` is indeed returning `obj`)

Comment: @lc. Yes, good point. I was trying to be too brief, at the expense of clarity!

Comment: Good point on the ref. I could use that instead. Thanks.

Comment: @LLL: No... don't.  Why aren't these instance methods?  They have a single input, which may as well be the `this` reference, and now you have a better design and one less problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# never copies a reference type.  If you pass in *obj* to your method and then return it, that is the same exact object instance you started with.

That does not create additional pressure for the GC.

Comment: From a lower-level.. would it be safe to assume the memory address of the object is just being copied over itself? Or does the CLR optimize this away?

Comment: You have one or more aliases to the exact same memory handle.  A handle is a level of indirection on top of a memory address.  That extra level of indirection allows the GC to move memory (if it is not explicitly pinned) to reduce heap fragmentation.

Answer (score 4):

> In C# an object passed into a method is passed via reference. The reference is only lost if the passed in object is re-instantiated with the keyword new

No and no, not by default at least.  By default *everything* is passed by value. It just so happens that, in the case of reference types, the thing being passed by value is a reference.

So, a *copy* of the reference is made.  This also disproves the second statement.  You can reassign the method argument all you like; you are simply modifying a copy.  This also changes the meaning of your question, because you go on to say...

> So, I like to do things like var obj = Alter(obj)(method 1)... I would argue the first one is better since if some daredevil coder later modifies the code to use a keyword "new"... existing code won't burn and die.

That situation will not occur.  Secondly, if you work with programmers who check in code that flat out doesn't work and that they didn't test, you have a bigger problem.  However, "using the `new` keyword" on the reference copy is irrelevant anyway (at least, in terms of affecting the original).  Even if you were correct in your approach this would be overly defensive.

My question to you is; if you have functions which serve only to mutate the state of its single input, then why isn't this method an instance method of the type to begin with?

Comment: Interesting part about the reference being a value type. I am looking for code to expose that now. The part about mutating, well, I don't know since I am more or less trying to improve my understanding of .NET instead of asking a specific question.

Comment: @LLL: Well, the reference isn't a value type in that it does not derive from `System.ValueType`, but it is copied when passed to a function.  Try this: `void foo(SomeClass x) { x = new SomeClass(); }`. Create an instance of `SomeType` and pass it to that function.  Notice that it remains unchanged in the calling code.

Comment: I thought that had to do more with the scope of x as a reference and it pointing at a new object instead of the referenced one... which it is, but I see now that it is passed by a value i.e. there's a second pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's safer to not modify parameters that are specified as input to a method. As for performance, memory consumption difference between these two are almost certainly going to be negligible, and definitely won't be the performance bottleneck in your program. It's a case of pre-mature optimization.

You should choose the cleaner, safer solution, unless you have evidence that the performance difference is causing a problem in your program.